# How to add margin top inside a material-ui container?

Tags: material-ui

I have this material-ui container example below the text is simply sticking to the upper top of the container, how to add margin to push it down ? also how to add a margin Right/Left to the container since it is taking up the whole screen.

```js
export default function FixedContainer() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <CssBaseline />
      <Container fixed>
        <Typography
          component="div"
          style={{
            backgroundColor: "#cfe8fc",
            height: "100vh",
            marginTop: "122px"
          }}
        >
          This must have a margin top not the conatainer
        </Typography>
      </Container>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add spacing between your text and the top of the container, padding would be better to use in the styles prop, instead of margin.

```
style={{
  backgroundColor: "#cfe8fc",
  height: "100vh",
  paddingTop: "122px"
}}
```

The `maxWidth` prop in the Container component can be used to assign the width to the container.

I've created a [sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/fixedcontainer-material-demo-forked-mulxo?file=/demo.js) out of your code.

Comment: so margin wont do anything then ?

Comment: Margin also works in the codesandbox, but margin moves the whole container down and text remains at the top of the container. You can play around with both padding and margin in the codesandbox example shared in the answer.